# Split date column on the basis of years in the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am working with the AdventureWorks2014 database and am using the following query.

```
select 
SUM(Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail.OrderQty) as 'Total Quantity',
SUM(Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail.LineTotal) as 'Total Amount',
Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.VendorID

from Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail
inner join Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader
on Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail.PurchaseOrderID =  Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderID

group by Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.VendorID, DATEPART(year,Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.OrderDate)
order by Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader.VendorID
```

This gives me the following output.

```
|------------------------------------|  
|Total Quantity|Total Amount|VendorID|
|15            |694.1655    |    1492|
|288           |12370.239   |    1492|
|45            |1931.7375   |    1492|
|180           |7682.6295   |    1492|
|9350          |150404.1    |    1494|
|1650          |26541.9     |    1494|
|550           |8847.3      |    1494|
|16500         |265419      |    1494|
|------------------------------------|
```

From what i understand, this is each year's data, i.e,the values 2011,2012,2013 and 2014, for each vendor. Which is why each vendor is repeated 4 times.

I need to have each of these years as a separate column in the output as follows.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Total Quantity|Total Amount|VendorID|2011Amount|2012Amount|2013Amount|2014Amount|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: use pivot.. You can find more about it on web

Comment: @ShakeerMirza thanks for the tip, i'll give it a shot...

Comment: @ShakeerMirza because you are aggregating more than 1 column I would actually recommend conditional aggregation.  When more than 1 column is in play PIVOT can be more difficult.  although in this case using window functions across the table to create distinct values wtill makes it somewhat easy to do PIVOT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot Method, make sure you first prepare the query how you want prior to pivoting.

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
       DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate) as [Year]
       ,SUM(pod.OrderQty) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate)) as TotalQuantity
       ,SUM(pod.LineTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate)) as TotalAmount
       ,pod.LineTotal as Amount
    FROM
       Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod
       INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh
       ON pod.PurchaseOrderId = poh.PurchaseOrderId
)

SELECT *
FROm
    cte
    PIVOT (
       SUM(Amount)
       FOR [Year] IN ([2011],[2012],[2013],[2014])
    ) p
```

Conditional Aggregation Method

```
SELECT
    SUM(pod.OrderQty) as TotalQuantity
    ,SUM(pod.LineTotal) as TotalAmount
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate) = 2011 THEN pod.LineTotal ELSE 0 END) as [2011Amount]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate) = 2012 THEN pod.LineTotal ELSE 0 END) as [2012Amount]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate) = 2013 THEN pod.LineTotal ELSE 0 END) as [2013Amount]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(year,poh.OrderDate) = 2014 THEN pod.LineTotal ELSE 0 END) as [2014Amount]
FROM
    Purchasing.PurchaseOrderDetail pod
    INNER JOIN Purchasing.PurchaseOrderHeader poh
    ON pod.PurchaseOrderId = poh.PurchaseOrderId
```

In this case I think I would go with the conditional aggregation method..... Please note I used Table Aliases to refer to the table rather than continuing to type the long names it is a good habit to get into.

This exact code is of course untested because you did not include test data and desired result but the techniques are the most standard way of doing this. Note when more than 1 column is involved in aggregation it is typically easiest to do conditional aggregation.